# Инсталляция программы

Tags: windowsinstaller

есть готовая программа со своими dll. Необходимо часть dll положить в папку program files x86 а другую часть в C:\windows\ 
Кто знает как возможно положить в системную папку при помощи инсталлятора (на данный момент использую advanced installer и в нем такой возможности не предусмотрено)

Comment: А зачем вам в системный каталог свои DLL пихать?